# Check private area validation in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-plugins

I am just starting to learn Codeigniter and work on a personal project.I have a login script working successfully, but am trying to get pointed down the correct path where to start looking at the authenticated sessions  to restrict unauthorized access

Comment: Question is not clear. Try explaining with some code if it supports the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In controller

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))  { 
  $this->load->view('home'); // Private area    
    } else {
  $this->load->view('login'); // Else redirect to Login Page    
}
```